# use if else in insert statement plsql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

i have plsql code that insert data from table1 to table2

and i want to put if statment to insert certain value in a specific column and this is my code

```
for rec_table1 in (
select * from table1 
where salary > 100)
loop
insert into table2 (
col1 , col2 , col3 col4 ,col5)
values 
(rec_table1.col1 , 
 rec_table1.col2,
 rec_table1.col3 , 
 rec_table1.col4 ,
if (rec_table1.col2 = 1)
  then
rec_table1.col2 
else
rec_table1.col5
end if
```

but it give me syntax error at the if statment

Answer (score 1):

A plain insert into with case would do just fine. There's no need to go for loops.

```
  INSERT INTO table2 (
     col1,col2,col3,col4,col5) 
        select col1 , col2,col3 col4,CASE col2
     WHEN 1 THEN col2
          ELSE col5
     END AS col5
     FROM table1 where salary > 100;
```

Answer (score 1):

`IF` is a PL/SQL statement and can't be used inside a SQL statement.

You *can* use a SQL `CASE` expression:

```
for rec_table1 in (select * from table1 
                   where salary > 100)
loop
  insert into table2 (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5)
  values (rec_table1.col1, rec_table1.col2,  rec_table1.col3, rec_table1.col4,
          case 
            when rec_table1.col2 = 1 then rec_table1.col2 
            else rec_table1.col5
          end);
END LOOP;
```

However the whole loop is inefficient and slow. You don't need it. This can be written as a single INSERT statement which will perform a lot better.

You can replace the complete LOOP .. END LOOP; part with the following INSERT statement:

```sql
insert into table2 (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5)
select col1, col2, col3, col4,           
       case 
          when col2 = 1 then col2 
          else col5
       end
from table1 
where salary > 100;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can manage it within one statement by using `decode()` as :

```
insert into table2 (col1 , col2 , col3 col4 ,col5)
select col1 , decode(col2,1,col2,col5) , col3, col4 ,col5 
  from table1 
 where salary > 100;
```

**OR** by using `case..when` expression as :

```
insert into table2 (col1 , col2 , col3 col4 ,col5)
select col1 , case when col2=1 then col2 else col5 end , col3, col4 ,col5 
  from table1 
 where salary > 100;
```

P.S. `decode()` is spesific to `Oracle DB`, `case..when` is generic.

Answer (score 0):

I believe, instead of **If-Else**, but you would have to implement **Case-When** syntax.

Here's the documentation: [Case-When](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems004.htm)

First focus on constructing the correct Select statement, then you can just insert values using output of the select query.

Comment: Oops, my bad! Thanks for pointing it out. I corrected the link.